# Site loading on port 443 and not on 80

Tags: html, ssl, websocket, apache2

I have site  which isn't really working properly on SSL certificate. 
The website works properly on 443 port with `SSLEngine off` directive in my configuration file, with `SSLEngine on` is responsing with 503 Error.
It also connects on port 80 by default and I don't really know where to change that because everywhere I have set port 443.

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.antoszbk.xyz/$1 [R,L]
```

configuration file (while working properly):

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/index.html
        ServerName antoszbk.xyz

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine off

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/www.antoszbk.xyz.csr
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www.antoszbk.xyz.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: *"It also connects on port 80 by default"* - "It" is the browser which uses plain HTTP as the default where no explicit protocol (like `https://`) is given.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in DNS Server Configuration. 
Certificate given to me by provider was set to `antoszbk.xyz` alias but in my SSL configuration I set it up to `www.antoszbk.xyz`. Still receive an error if trying to connect by IPv6 (AAAA record) redirection but it is a matter of time for the DNS to process it.